# How to search text containing non-ASCII characters with Django icontains query?

Tags: python, django

I would like to search for text that contains non-ASCII characters using ASCII search keywords, so that '*t*' matches '*ṭ*'.

For example, given a `Book` object with Sanskrit title '*Aṣṭasāhasrikā-prajñāpāramitā-sūtra*' in field `title`, I would like the following query to return it:

```
Book.objects.filter(title__icontains='prajna')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to create another field `ascii_title` in the `Book` object and (a) save a copy of the title with diacritics removed in there automatically, (b) use only the `ascii_title` field during search, first removing diacritics from the search keyword as well:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ascii_title = remove_diacritics(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

Book.objects.filter(ascii_title__icontains=remove_diacritics('prajñā'))
```

You can find inspiration for `remove_diacritics()` from [`django.utils.text.slugify()` implementation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/utils/text/#slugify):

```
import unicodedata
def remove_diacritics(value):
     return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```

In case you are using PostgreSQL, there's another possibility - use `UNACCENT` queries as explained [here](http://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql/#unaccented-query):

```
Book.objects.filter(title__unaccent=remove_diacritics('prajñā'))
```